# Android: Google Sign-In switch to other activity without losing login data

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, google-signin

am using [Google Sign-in for android](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java#L51-L55) to login my app with google account. I created a menu button, this button is for another activity.The question is how to switch between activities, without losing login credentials?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
        case R.id.sign_out_button:
            signOut();
            break;
        case R.id.disconnect_button:
            revokeAccess();
            break;
        case R.id.menuButton:
            gotoMeniu();
            break;
    }
}
```

My simple method for switching to another activity, when am logged in:

```
private void gotoMeniu(){

    String welcomeMessage = mStatusTextView.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, welcomeMessage);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

My error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object
>   reference

I think it occurs, because my code is still being executed after method with intent.

Answer (score 1):

if I correctly understood your problem, I would suggest to create a class "Session", in which you can store data via [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Just google it, I think you will find the appropriate link.

About your error:
check whether you initialized the button before doing a click on it.
otherwise check the visibility of the button, a little bit about [NPE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Preventing_NullPointerException)